# Remove url parameter using wordpress

Tags: url-rewriting, urls

how can I remove a parameter from a URL in wordpress? for example if I have the following URL: http://domain.com/?cat=4&paged=2&order=DESC 
How can I remove paged from it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use pretty permalink. Please read [this docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) from WordPress Codex for full information.

Answer (score 3):

Using [remove_query_arg()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_query_arg/) to remove query string from the URL.

For example, to remove the `paged` query string from the current page URL:

```
remove_query_arg('paged', false); //FALSE, means to use the current URL
```

If you have specific URL:

```
remove_query_arg('paged', 'http://domain.com/?cat=4&paged=2&order=DESC');
```

Or if you have multiple query string and you wanted to remove them:

```
$paramaters = array('cat', 'paged', 'order');
remove_query_arg($paramaters, false); //FALSE, means to use the current URL
```